# How do I add a cloned VM to Active Directory without conflicting with other clones?

Tags: active-directory, virtualization

I'm not sure of the exact terminology here as I'm not a network pro but I've run into this issue a couple of times as a developer. Edits encouraged!

If I create a virtual machine on a desktop and add it to active directory and then distribute the VM to other network users to use, how do we mitigate active directory (SID) conflicts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest method is to run [newsid.exe from Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897418.aspx) on each distributed VM.
It changes the SID (and optionally renames the PC) so conflicts don't occur.
It's best to create the VM while the guest is an a Workgroup. Then distribute the VM, run newsid.exe and then add the guest to the domain.

Alternatively you can use [Sysprep](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302577) to prepare the VM, it achieves the same thing and is more of an automated process.

Answer (score 2):

You should always create a master image using sysprep and then use it as a part of the VM library. If you are using SCVMM, it becomes easy to perform an action like this. You can have the VM templates/clones added to the SCVMM library and then deploy it on a need basis.